# how to show output as same with input while the number of the input is not described?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

main()
{
    int i = 1, n, numbers;
    cout << "Enter numbers of input : "; cin >> n; //asking how much input (as number)
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter input number " << i << " = "; //to enter the input(as number)
        cin >> numbers;
    } while (i <= n);
    getch();
}
```

the previous code was asking an user to input how much "input" user wants and to input numbers as much as the user wants.
what do i need to do to have output as :

Input number 1 : "numbers"

input number 2 : "numbers"

.

.

input number n : "numbers"

Comment: `#include <iostream.h>` has never been part of Standard C++. And neither has `#include <conio.h>`, come to that.

Comment: my book is " a tour of c++" and the problem is my lecturer still using borland. :)

Comment: @JonathanLimbong Yeah, that sucks, man. That was C++ 25 years ago, (and barely even that then). The world changes. Embracing a more modern C++ (ideally at least through C++11, which completely changed the landscape of the modern C++ world), should be a mission of academia, not an obstacle to avoid at the expense of its students.

Comment: i need to code twice for every lesson, in borland and code::blocks.

Comment: @JonathanLimbong You need to use int array for saving numbers and printing it at later time.

Comment: @AlFahad is that the only way ? because the output of array input wont showed as i want.

Comment: Yes @JonathanLimbong by using array you can show numbers exactly in the way you want. You need to get all inputs (in loop) and save it in an integer array then print out all values from that array (using another loop).

Answer (score 0):

You are not incrementing `i` in the loop.
You can do `++i` while printing `i`.

`cout << "Enter input number " << ++i << " = ";`

Comment: yes, i  accidentally delete that. 
can i change the cin in the loop to `cin>>numbers[i]` and adding `i=i++` after ? to have multiple input that i can process or show later ?

Comment: You should never do `i=i++` its undefined behavior https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior